# why does do-release-upgrade 20.04->22.04 install apache httpd?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, apache2, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

Just upgraded 20.04 to 22.04 and it went great ([short of 1 minor bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1986842)),
and to my surprise, do-release-upgrade installed apache httpd! unfortunately I need port 80 for other stuff, leaving me with 2 questions:

1. Why does do-release-upgrade 20.04->22.04 install apache httpd?
2. what are the consequences of deleting do-release-upgrade's apache httpd? (i need port 80 for Docker stuff, and afaik i don't need apache httpd for anything)

edit: seems to be related to me having php-fpm and php-cli installed (for use with nginx, not apache):

```
root@devad22:/home/hans# aptitude why apache2
i   php                   Depends    php8.1                                         
i A php8.1                Depends    libapache2-mod-php8.1 | php8.1-fpm | php8.1-cgi
i A libapache2-mod-php8.1 Recommends apache2
```

Comment: I've release-upgraded quite a few desktops from 20.04 to 22.04, and NONE of them installed apache. So your experience is not universal. Apt has a `--simulate` flag: Simulate removing that apache package and look for unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that if you have the `PHP` package installed, but not the `apache2` package installed, before upgrading, do-release-upgrade will install `apache2` during the upgrade, quoting the upgrade `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` log:

```
  MarkInstall php:amd64 < 2:7.4+75 -> 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Installing php8.1 as Depends of php
    MarkInstall php8.1:amd64 < none -> 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2 @un uN Ib > FU=0
    Installing libapache2-mod-php8.1 as Depends of php8.1
      MarkInstall libapache2-mod-php8.1:amd64 < none -> 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2 @un uN Ib > FU=0
      Installing php8.1-cli as Depends of libapache2-mod-php8.1
        MarkInstall php8.1-cli:amd64 < none -> 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2 @un uN Ib > FU=0
        Installing php8.1-opcache as Depends of php8.1-cli
          MarkInstall php8.1-opcache:amd64 < none -> 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2 @un uN > FU=0
        Installing php8.1-readline as Depends of php8.1-cli
          MarkInstall php8.1-readline:amd64 < none -> 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2 @un uN > FU=0
      Installing apache2-bin as Depends of libapache2-mod-php8.1
        MarkInstall apache2-bin:amd64 < none -> 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1 @un uN Ib > FU=0
        Installing libapr1 as Depends of apache2-bin
          MarkInstall libapr1:amd64 < none -> 1.7.0-8build1 @un uN > FU=0
        Installing libaprutil1 as Depends of apache2-bin
          MarkInstall libaprutil1:amd64 < none -> 1.6.1-5ubuntu4 @un uN > FU=0
        Installing libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 as Depends of apache2-bin
          MarkInstall libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 < none -> 1.6.1-5ubuntu4 @un uN > FU=0
        Installing libaprutil1-ldap as Depends of apache2-bin
          MarkInstall libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 < none -> 1.6.1-5ubuntu4 @un uN > FU=0
        Installing liblua5.3-0 as Depends of apache2-bin
          MarkInstall liblua5.3-0:amd64 < none -> 5.3.6-1build1 @un uN > FU=0
      Installing apache2 as Recommends of libapache2-mod-php8.1
        MarkInstall apache2:amd64 < none -> 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1 @un uN Ib > FU=0
        Installing apache2-data as Depends of apache2
          MarkInstall apache2-data:amd64 < none -> 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1 @un uN > FU=0
        Installing apache2-utils as Depends of apache2
          MarkInstall apache2-utils:amd64 < none -> 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1 @un uN > FU=0
```

> 1. Why does do-release-upgrade 20.04->22.04 install apache httpd?

people over at irc://irc.libera.chat#Ubuntu seems to think it's a *depepdency bug*

> 2. what are the consequences of deleting do-release-upgrade's apache httpd? (i need port 80 for Docker stuff, and afaik i don't need apache httpd for anything)

My best guess is, no consequences